# use if-else logic in where clause in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to use if-else logic in where clause in T-SQL? or do I have to implement the logic by using subquery?

Comment: @Filip De Vos: Maybe you were right assuming SQL Server, but FYI, the SQL dialect used in Sybase is also called T-SQL (Transact-SQL).

Answer (score 4):

Use [Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
(case foo when bar then baz else fizz end)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a case statement in a where clause, but it can generate performance issues, so you may want to try a different approach if you have a large dataset. A correlated subquery would not be a good alternative approach; a derived table or CTE might be.